# Using wildcards in a Ruby string

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say I have something like:

```
Image.from_file("path/to_file/#{$variable_name}_[some_number].png")
```

I don't know what `[some_number]` will be, but I know that it will always be there.

How can I write a regex (presumably) so that it doesn't matter what `[some_number]` is?

Thanks.

--- edit ---

@DavidGrayson you're right. I don't need a regex at all (sorry for the wild goose chase folks).

Looks like I can get exactly what I need from `newFileName = Dir.glob("#{variable_name}_*.png").first` then `Image.from_file("path/to_file/#{$newFileName}")` etc.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: Which is the result you want to achieve after the regex?

Comment: Maybe a regex is not what I'm looking for. I basically want ```[some_number]``` to be a wildcard.

Comment: In general, when you open a file you can't use wildcard; you have to give the actual file name, and a relative or absolute path to it.  It sounds like you are hoping for `FileUtils.rm` to have some feature it doesn't have.  I don't know what you are trying to do, but maybe a good general strategy would be to get a directory listing, use a regex to search it for the files that are interesting, and then perform some action on those files.

Comment: You might try using something like `Dir.glob('abcd_*.png')`; maybe you don't need the powerful features of regexes.

Comment: @DavidGrayson you're right. I don't need a regex at all (sorry for the wild goose chase folks). Looks like I can get exactly what I need from ```newFileName = Dir.glob("#{variable_name_}*.png").first``` then ```Image.from_file("path/to_file/#{$newFileName}")``` etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can have variables in regexes in ruby: `/#{$variable_name}_\d+\.png/`

Comment: No need for `[\d]+`.  You can just do `\d+`.

Comment: Sorry, I should be clearer. It needs to be in a string.

    ("path/to_file\/#{$variable_name}_\d+\.png")

ends up as 
   path/to_file/variable_name_d+.png

Comment: Can you clarify your goal a bit. Are you trying to create a regex to use with something like grep, or are you trying to create a string that replaces \d with a number?

Comment: no, my string already has a number in it. I want to find the string no matter what number it is.

Comment: Ok, but what are you trying to do with the string? Say your string is "path/to_file/file_a_1234\.png", what is the goal?

Comment: I'm going to end up manipulating the image in something like Image Magick or just for arguments sake, delete it.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the string"?  To me, the word "find" implies there is some collection of strings you are searching through.  Are you searching through a directory listing?  Could you edit the question above to give some example inputs and outputs?